# "Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed " When trying to View a list

Tags: r

I had the problem when I tried to view a List generated trough a function that computes the intersect/difference of two sets of 20000 observations each.
The function in question:

```
jeepers.creepers<-function(dfx,dfy,by.x,by.y){
  SetX<-dfx[[by.x]]
  SetY<-dfy[[by.y]]
  Union.X.Y<-intersect(SetX,SetY)
  Difference.in.X<-setdiff(SetX,Union.X.Y)
  Difference.in.Y<-setdiff(SetY,Union.X.Y)
  result<-list(Union.X.Y,Difference.in.X,Difference.in.Y)
  names(result)<-c("Union of SetX and SetY",
               "Unique in SetX",
               "Unique in SetY")

  return(result)
}
```

It gave me this error:

```
Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Nevertheless I could view the elements individually with

```
View(list$element)
```

When I use summary on the list it gives me:

```
                       Length Class  Mode   
Union of SetX and SetY  8584  -none- numeric
Unique in SetX         15334  -none- numeric
Unique in SetY             0  -none- numeric
```

Does anyone knows whats happening?

Comment: R has a wierd (and super annoying) way of handling NAs. if your output is empty then `nchar(output)` will return `integer(0)`. You can get around this by adding another if statement with `if(length(nchar(output)) > 0){...}`

Comment: I did tests with the function with far less observations, but also generating 0 obs in "Unique in SetY" And I had no problem viewing those lists

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue when trying to view a data set I imported. I could also view individual elements but not the whole data set. I solved it by converting it to a data frame using `as.data.frame(dataset)`.